# Ticks plotted with an offset in colorbar

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

**Problem:** I am plotting the colorbar using Matplotlib, but these ticks are set at 0.0, 0.1.. to 0.5.

[image]

I wanted to get more intervals in between, but that leads to me having this following problem : Irregularly spaced tick labels.

In this picture, I have marked in red the offset in the ticks.

[image]

**Code:**

```
plt.pcolor(data_mod, vmin = 0.01, vmax = 0.5, cmap=cmap)
cb = plt.colorbar(extend='both')
cb.set_label('CPRESS', fontsize=7, labelpad=-10, y=1.05, rotation=0)
tick_locator = ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins = 10)
cb.locator = tick_locator
cb.update_ticks()
plt.imshow(data_mod)
```

What could I be doing wrong? Would it be possible to make the ticks just on top (starting) of the colors?

Comment: Using the `ticker.MaxNLocator` you explicitely ask for those bins; so it would make sense not to use it. You probably introduced it to get around a different issue, so it would make sense to edit the question to ask about the real issue here.

Comment: I used ticker.MaxNLocator to set the nbins to 10. The real issue is how could the ticks be on the top (starting) of the color? What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Using `ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins = 10)` you impose the locator without changing the color normalization. So this is what you are doing wrong. Solution don't use it. As said, please edit the question to the underlying problem (including a [mcve] would help here).

Comment: Thanks, I have made the changes and would be grateful if I could find a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could imagine you want to fix the boundaries of colors shown on the plot and in the colorbar to the values of `numpy.linspace(0,.5,11)`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
cmap = plt.get_cmap("jet",11)

data = np.random.rand(10,10)/2.
norm=matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(np.linspace(0,0.5,11),11)
plt.pcolor(data, norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
cb = plt.colorbar(extend='both', ticks=np.linspace(0,0.5,11))
cb.set_label('CPRESS', fontsize=7, labelpad=-10, y=1.05, rotation=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]